# Keep Carriage Returns when BULK_INSERTING .csv into SQL Server 2008 (Express)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, import

I am exporting data from my old recruitment database into my new one to save paying extortionate costs. I am almost all there using BULK_INSERT (do not have full SSIS with SQL Server 2008 Express and the Import/Export Wizard does not have a KEEP NULL option which is important to me so am left with BULK_INSERT).

Anyhow, it's all looking good with my .csv and BULK_INSERT bar one pesky column. The destination column in the one table (Client) to which I am importing is:-

```
Client_Notes (ntext, null)
```

I am using the following syntax for the insert:-

```
BEGIN TRAN SAJ
BULK INSERT Client
FROM 'c:\MAIN SHARE\IMPORT TEST.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
FIRSTROW = 2,
KEEPNULLS
)
GO
-- COMMIT TRAN SAJ
--ROLLBACK TRAN SAJ
```

Now the data in my .csv for this column will be of this nature:-

```
abc
123
45
67891011121314
```

When it gets imported it looks like this:-

```
abc1234567891011121314
```

and also has funny characters where the carriage returns were and where it has truncated. Is there a way to keep the formatting in this column when importing? I have heard of having to use a 'format file', but cannot find details of what I need to do exactly here.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
```

If it doens't work, Open the .csv file with notepad/ultraedit and post its content in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that didn't work and when I run with ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n', - it just comes back with:- '0 rows affected'.

Comment: Should I try FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', with ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n', or with ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',?

Comment: First only field, and afterwords both.

Comment: Thanks - will try this. I am not in the office today so will try it tomorrow morning. If neither works I will post a row of data from the .csv as suggested.

Comment: Ok - neither of those suggestions worked. It just says 0 rows affected when I execute with FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', and either ROWTERMINATOR. Even if I shorten my .csv to one rows worth of data it is too big to paste here - is there any other way I can display it?

Comment: Host it somewhere with one line and put a link to the .csv :)

Comment: But of course! Here she is with one row (File/Download - look at the Client Notes column, you may need to double click to see all the text):- https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2buP1XklhdRLTNMN3FaQjJUY3FpMFBQakZsSmFHUQ

Comment: I'll have to check at home. Here at work I don't have access to google docs :|

Comment: I dunno if I can help you. But I'll try :D